# How to create redirect after auth user, vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got token and it thing stored in vue state and local.storage.
How to create redirect after auth and after get token?

At the moment I have this code, Its redirect, but after get token redirect isn't happens and without check token.

I need to check token and redirect to fullPath, pls help!

```
var Auth = {
  loggedIn: false,
  login: function () { this.loggedIn = true },
  logout: function () { this.loggedIn = false }
}
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth) && !Auth.loggedIn) {
    next({
      path: '/login',
      query: {redirect: '/'}
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it should work like that:

- user enters login/pass
- vuex action `userLogin` fired
- `userLogin` action sends data to server, server returns token
- `userLogin` action saves token to the `localStorage`
- `userLogin` commits mutation `USER_LOGIN` with token and/or user credentials

Then to make auto-login with saved token (after browser closing, etc)

- on the app start you should call `userLoginLocal` vuex action
- `userLoginLocal` reads token from `localStorage`
- `userLoginLocal` should validate token or/and send to server for validation
- `userLoginLocal` commits mutation `USER_LOGIN` with token and/or user credentials (if token is valid)

NOTES: 
Mutation `USER_LOGIN` makes `isLoggedIn = true`

Comment: Ok, thanks! But I decided, like this: `router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.state.token === null) {
      next({
        path: '/login',
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})`